# How to create a function that is secure and can be used in many places in Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I have read part of the manual about `+page.server.ts` files for sveltekit and we have methods/functions that allow the load/get, post, patch and delete methods but I would like to have a method/function that can be used in many places. I have created one in my `utils.ts` file but I wonder if I'm exposing my API tokens since I have to import this method into my `+page.svelte`

Answer (score 1):

Anything you import in `+page.svelte` or `+page.js` is exposed to the client, so that would include any API tokens used there.

What you probably want to do is making your own API endpoints using `+server.js` routes and use regular fetches or forms to **that** endpoint which in turn uses your external API and the tokens.  Since that would be fully server side nothing is exposed to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that really makes sense and will work